Any solution for this error: Timed out while connecting to named pipe.?
I can not open the old form again. I get this error:
Timed out while connecting to named pipe


I searched and followed some steps but without solution

Disabled my firewall
Change warning level to none in the options of "Windows Forms Designer"
Changed target .Net from net8 to net7
Deleted .vs, obj , bin
Creating new form also result in the same problem

Any other solution ? I use VS 2022 community
Call Stack
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerProcess.d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerProcess.d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerHostFactory.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.<>c__DisplayClass25_1.<<-ctor>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d__27.MoveNext()  


Post the (relevant) code that produces this problem. Judging from the message alone, it seems to be trying to do a connection on a pipe where no one is listening.

@Alejandro No code just empty windows forms project

Did you try to create blank new project to validate is it issue in project or VS settings?

@Jivopis yes the project has a problem because new project display the form fine. I dont know how I can identify the project problem ?

Compare the source of the working one with the one that doesn't work.

No source to compare. When I add new form I get the same problem.

I changed target framework to net471 then save, reload then change it back to net8-windows then save, close VS and open the project again and now the form loaded normally !!!

Why is this a thing? It worked for me. Thanks.
